# Create yml file using python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I am able to create the `stories.yml` file using python but I want output like this:

```
- story: feelings of worthless
   
   steps:
   - intent: feelings of worthless
   - action: utter_feelings_of_worthless
```

but I am getting this:

```
- steps:

    intent: feelings of worthless

    response: utter_feelings_of_worthless

  story: feelings of worthless
```

This is code I have:

```
stories = {}
mylist = []
for key in intentsToExamples:
    stories['story'] = 'story ' + key
    stories['steps'] = {'intent':key,'response':'utter ' + key}
    mylist.append(stories.copy())
    
with open('stories.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(mylist, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Could you add `intensToExamples` to complete your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding `sort_keys=False` to the `yaml.dump()` call. By default `yaml.dump` sorts in alphabetic order while creating the yml file. This was causing 'steps' to come first while 'story' late.